# Error setting cookie and getting a json response with router.post in express, node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie with a post method in order to do some db query and put it back in the cookie value, as well as returning a json with the user data.
It works, the cookie is set and I get the json on http://localhost:8080
but I get a message from the compiler:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

How can I fix it so it won’t make this error?

my file structure is:
root/ app.js

root/controllers/ cookie.controller.js

root/routes/ cookie.route.js

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || process.argv[2] || 8080;

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('./routes/cookies'));
app.use(cors());

app.listen(port, () => console.log('cookie-parser demo is up on port: ' + port));
```

**cookie.route.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const cookieController = require('../controllers/cookies');

const router = express.Router();

router.use(require('cookie-parser')());

router.post('/', router.use(cookieController.getCookie));

module.exports = router;
```

**cookie.controller.js**

```
exports.getCookie = (req, res, next) => {
    let auth = req.cookies.auth;
    //...db queries, get userData

    let userData = {
        id: '123',
        token: 'sfsdfs34',
        email: 'user@gmail.com'
    };

    // if cookie doesn't exist, create it
    if (!auth) {
        res.status(200)
            .cookie('auth', userData.id)
            .json({ message: 'it works!', user: userData });
        req.cookies.auth = userData.id;
    }
    next();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying the request cookie headers after sending the response at the end of your `getCookie` controller. You should remove `req.cookies.auth = userData.id`, and use `res.cookie()` instead before sending the response.

```
const express = require('express')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

const app = express()

app.use(cookieParser())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.cookies.auth) {
    res.cookie('auth', { id: '123' })
  }

  res.json({ message: 'It worked!' })
})

app.listen(8080, () => console.log('http://localhost:8080))
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved after deleting the cors from app.js